# How to Change Label Text to Direct page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want is after i login  i want to change my label.text in my home.aspx 
what is should i do
.
Problems in VB.net than ASP.net
Always i do is

```
Home.aspx.label.text = userTxt.text
```

But on this asp  i got a problem on that

```
If userTxt.Text <> "" And passTxt.Text <> "" Then
    cmd = New OleDbCommand("Select * from loginClient where emailaddress = '" & userTxt.Text & "' and password = '" & passTxt.Text & "'", cnn)
    rdoleb = cmd.ExecuteReader
    Response.Redirect("main.aspx")

    rdoleb.Close()

    If rdoleb.Read = True Then
        If userTxt.Text = rdoleb.Item(2) And passTxt.Text = rdoleb.Item(3) Then
            rdoleb.Close()
        End If
```

Comment: You have a `Response.Redirect` after your `ExecuteReader`.  Unless `rdoleb` has global scope, you won't be able to access it after the redirect.  Plus you've left the `OleDbDataReader` open, and you're wide open to SQL Injection attacks since you're passing the user entered text directly into the SQL command.

Comment: Also, **WHAT** error or behavior are you seeing?  Posting code (that doesn't even look like it will **work**) without giving us the error (and where it occurs) or a description of the behavior will get you nowhere.